# Hostname of server for bulk-e-mail

Tags: email, linux, bulk-email

I am using a VPS that will be sending out e-mails to thousands of (legitimate) e-mail contacts.

I have everything about ready, so mail passes various checks for SPF and DKIM.

One thing left is the hostname of the server, this is set by my hosting company and is using one of  their TLDs. I can change the hostname but it looks pretty complicated and I am wondering if there is any need.

Will keeping their hostname adversely affect the e-mail i.e going to spam or being blocked? I have checked the TLD and it doesn't appear on any blacklists so that is not a concern. Is there anything else I need to consider?

Comment: You are talking about **bulk** email. It will make some (even if not big) difference.